# Tomcat not running, "eval: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java: not found"

Tags: java, tomcat

I've installed Tomcat server on my Ubuntu desktop, and when I run it it says that Tomcat has started, but I can't browse the interface, so I made some research and found a problem in `logs/catalina.out` file:

```
/home/user/Programs/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java: not found
./bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java: not found
```

I don't even have the `java-8-openjdk` file in the `jvm` directory, and the only things that it contains is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24  22  2014 default-java -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20  16 16:06 java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096  24 14:52 java-6-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096   2 20:58 java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096  24 16:38 java-8-oracle
```

I've checked environmental variables and they look OK. What is the problem?

EDIT:

As I noticed Tomcat uses JRE_HOME instead of JAVA_HOME, instead of the fact that it is properly set, how to change it?

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/shota/Programs/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/shota/Programs/apache-tomcat-8.0.26
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/shota/Programs/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/shota/Programs/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/shota/Programs/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/shota/Programs/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/tomcat.pid
Existing PID file found during start.
Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Tomcat started.
```

Comment: Sounds like you have manually tinkered with the JVM's known to Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please post the value of  "JAVA_HOME"?? Try using [export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/]

Comment: This is echo $JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this issue fixed by creating setenv.sh file in bin directory and by setting JAVA_HOME there.

Comment: Could you explain what you did exactly, please?

Comment: just add create the file an add
export JAVA_HOME="<your java path>"